# R and RGtk2 in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: r, macos, gtk

Has anybody succeeded in installing this lately? I am aware of an existing thread that addresses this, but I haven't been able to make it work. Also, it's from 2010 so maybe there's a more up-to-date approach?

Specifically, I have tried to work with these:

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
>
> RGtk2_2.20.25
>
> cairoDevice_2.19
>
> GTK_2.18.5-X11
>
> echo $PATH
>
> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
>
> echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
>
> /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:

and following several instructions found online, but every time I try to:

> R
>
> >library(RGtk2)

I am always prompted with the error:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :   unable to load
> shared object
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RGtk2/libs/RGtk2.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RGtk2/libs/RGtk2.so,
> 6): Library not loaded:
> /Library/Frameworks/GTK+.framework/Versions/2.24.X11/Resources/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.dylib
> Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RGtk2/libs/RGtk2.so
> Reason: image not found

Clues? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can just tell you that with the macports build of R I can install (from source of course) and load it just fine. My PATH: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin`

Comment: But I still use Snow Leopard.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but being a total newbie in mac os x (I've had this laptop for ~week now, coming from Linux) I'm not sure I'll get the recipe right. Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it all. You need GTK version 2.24.X11, which you can get from here: http://r.research.att.com/#other. Download the package for GTK_2.24.17-X11. And you need XQuartz.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing GTK from http://r.research.att.com/libs/GTK_2.24.17-X11.pkg and XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/. Errors when loading `rattle` package can be solved in the same way.